# How to import data, select variables, and generate plots with shiny modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to upload data and then select variables from the uploaded data to generate a scatter plot.

1. Import module: Import data from csv file and display preview table
2. Select module: Select variables from imported dataset
3. Scatterplot module: Generate a scatterplot based on selected variables.

The concerns I have involve

1. Locating the imported data in the right module.
2. Updating the selectInput options with variables from the csv file
3. Connecting the modules the right way

To resolve this, I feel that I must add an `observe` somewhere and connect it to other modules. Something like this `observe({updateSelectInput(session, "var1", choices = names(dtreact()))})`

Right now the app does not run and outputs this error: `Error in varselect_ui("select") : object 'dtreact' not found`

Here's a link to an example [.csv file](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/vcd/UKSoccer.csv)

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)



scatter_plot <- function(dataset, xvar, yvar) {
  
  x <- rlang::sym(xvar)
  y <- rlang::sym(yvar)
  
  p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = !!x, y = !!y)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)),
          axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.1)))
  
  return(p)
  
}

importUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
    tableOutput(ns("contents"))
  )
  
}

importSE <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, 
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 dtreact <- reactive({
                   file <- input$file1
                   if (is.null(file))
                     return(NULL)
                   read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
                 })
                 
                 
                 output$contents <- renderTable({
                   dtreact()
                 })
          }
  )
  
}

varselect_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  var_choices <- names(dtreact)
  tagList(selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Select X variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL),
          selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Select Y variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL))
}

varselect_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
  return(
    list(
      xvar = reactive({input$xvar}),
      yvar = reactive({input$yvar})
    )
  )
                 }
  )
}

scatterplot_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("plot1"))
  
}

scatterplot_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, 
               function(input, output, session, dataset, plot1vars, plot2vars) {
  
  plot1_obj <- reactive({
    p <- scatter_plot(dataset, xvar = plot1vars$xvar(), yvar = plot1vars$yvar())
    return(p)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot1_obj()
  })
  }
  )
}






ui <- fluidPage(
  importUI("import"),
  varselect_ui("select"),
  scatterplot_ui("scatter")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  importSE("import")
  varselect_server("select")
  scatterplot_server("scatter")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Code was adapted from [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicate-bet-modules.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `observe`, but a smart way to link the outputs of the modules to the inputs of the modules. Therefore, use `return` in the modules that produce data that should be used by other modules and store these values in the main `server` function in variables. These variables you can then use as the input to other modules. It's also important that if you pass reactives as inputs to modules, they need to be unevaluated (so pass `dataset` instead of `dataset()`):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)



scatter_plot <- function(dataset, xvar, yvar) {
  
  x <- rlang::sym(xvar)
  y <- rlang::sym(yvar)
  
  p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = !!x, y = !!y)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)),
          axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.1)))
  
  return(p)
  
}

importUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
    tableOutput(ns("contents"))
  )
  
}

importSE <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, 
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 dtreact <- reactive({
                   file <- input$file1
                   if (is.null(file))
                     return(NULL)
                   read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
                 })
                 
                 
                 output$contents <- renderTable({
                   dtreact()
                 })
                 
                 return(dtreact)
               }
  )
  
}

varselect_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  var_choices <- ""
  tagList(selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Select X variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL),
          selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Select Y variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL))
}

varselect_server <- function(id, dataset) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 observeEvent(dataset(), {
                   updateSelectInput(session,
                                     "xvar",
                                     choices = names(dataset()))
                   updateSelectInput(session,
                                     "yvar",
                                     choices = names(dataset()))
                 })
                 
                 return(
                   list(
                     xvar = reactive({input$xvar}),
                     yvar = reactive({input$yvar})
                   )
                 )
               }
  )
}

scatterplot_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("plot1"))
  
}

scatterplot_server <- function(id, dataset, plot1vars, plot2vars) {
  moduleServer(id, 
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 plot1_obj <- reactive({
                   req(dataset())
                   p <- scatter_plot(dataset(), xvar = plot1vars(), yvar = plot2vars())
                   return(p)
                 })
                 
                 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                   plot1_obj()
                 })
               }
  )
}






ui <- fluidPage(
  importUI("import"),
  varselect_ui("select"),
  scatterplot_ui("scatter")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- importSE("import")
  plotvars <- varselect_server("select", dataset = dataset)
  scatterplot_server("scatter", dataset = dataset, plot1vars = plotvars$xvar,
                     plot2vars = plotvars$yvar)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: good one..........